# NAudio: Is it safe to reuse an existing AsioOut instance to play a queue of files?

Tags: c#, naudio, asio

In looking at the NAudio AsioOut class, it seems clear that instances are meant to be destroyed and recreated every time a new file is played through the output.  The Init method specifically throws an InvalidOperationException if the instance already has a source stream.  Generally it is not a problem to dispose and recreate the Asio output under normal circumstances, however, in one case I would like to avoid doing so because I am sending the output to a convolver set up as an Asio driver. Each time the driver is initialized, it has to reload a large convolution filter, so when playing back gapless tracks, the delay is annoying.

In order to avoid the delay, I have an idea to not dispose the AsioOut instance if it already exists, and the bit depth and sampling rate of the next file in the queue is the same as the last file.  The issue is that I have to call Init on the AsioOut class to pass it the next file to be played, which will throw the above mentioned exception.  Is it safe to change the Init method to avoid throwing the exception if I ensure the bit depth, sampling rate, and number of output channels has not changed between files?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.  If you use a MixingSampleProvider, and set the ReadFully property to true, you can keep adding AudioFileReaders without having to reinitialize the AsioOut instance, as long as those files have the same sample rate and bit depth.  Mark Heath wrote a blog post in which he discussed a helper class called AutoDisposeFileReader that is useful here.